# I have repeated date values in my x axis. How do i create a different row with a single average of those values?

Tags: python, datetime, plot

I have been working with a dataset which contains information about houses that have been sold on a particular market. There are two columns, 'price', and 'date'.

I would like to make a line plot to show how the prices of this market have chaged over time.

The problem is, I see that some houses have been sold at the same date but with a diferent price.

So ideally i would need to get the mean/average price of the house sold on each date before plotting.

So for example, if I had something like this:

**DATE  /                PRICE**

02/05/2015      /     $100

02/05/2015      /     $200

I would need to get a new row with the following average:

**DATE          /      PRICE**

02/05/2015      /      $150

I just havent been able to figure it out yet. I would appreciate anyone who could guide me in this matter. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the format of your input data and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using pandas:

`pd.groupby('DATE')['PRICE'].mean()`

Comment: Cant believe it was this easy. Thank you so much Victor.